# When I exit game via exit game node, Unreal tries to send a crash report

Tags: crash, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I made a small node that will exit the game when I press escape. This issue wasn't happening at first but a crash report shows up every time I exit the game using it. I can just exit out of it, but it is annoying.

[Script to exit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfbo8.png)

[Crash Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9K2j.png)

Comment: 1. You should make sure to get the proper stack trace, otherwise debugging this won't be possible (I presume). 2. If you want to quit the game, use the "Quit Game" Node. I don't even know what "Exit" does and couldn't find any documentation for it.

Comment: I changed to the quit game node, but that doesn't matter because now it happens if it closes in any way.